# Делал форму отправки для сайта, но при исполнении перекидывает на страницу обработчика php

Tags: php

Вот код HTML и JS

```
    <?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];

    $subject = "Возник вопрос";
    $mailTo = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "Вам пришло сообщение от".$name.".\n\n".$message.".\n\n".$phone;

    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header ("Location: index.php?mailsend");
}

 ?>

    <section class="contacts-main">
    <div class="top-contacts">
        <h2>Остались вопросы?</h2>
        <p>Заполните форму обратной связи и мы с радостью ответим вам!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-contacts">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/assets/img/contacts-main.svg" alt="">
        <form action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/mail.php" method="post">
            <label for="send-name">Ваше имя</label>
            <input class="send-name" type="text" name="name">
            <label for="send-phone">Ваш телефон</label>
            <input class="send-phone" type="tel" name="phone">
            <label for="send-text">Ваш email</label>
            <input class="send-text" type="text" name="text">
            <label for="send-text">Ваше сообщение</label>
            <input class="send-text" type="text" name="text">
            <input class="button-send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Как называется файл который вы приложили?

Comment: У вас форма ведет на сам обработчик mail.php, поэтому и редирект туда идет. Поставьте в action="#" и обработчик отработает на этой же странице

Answer (score 0):

Я создал index.php залил в него Ваш код.
у Вас вообще не отрабатывает If так как в форме у кнопки отсутствует атрибут name="submit"

```
 <input class="button-send" type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
```

Дальше не проверял работу кода.

Comment: Я проверил, теперь он теперь при отправке выдаёт ошибку Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() in index.php:1 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in index.php on line 1